# Previous page in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to put `request.referer` in a `link_to` tag. I have a page that is called by two different pages, and I would like to use a link to go back(if there is a back page, otherwise, put a default one). So far I tried this.

```
  <%= link_to "Return", request.referer %>
```

But I get an error saying `undefined method referer`.

Also tried in the controller something like:

```
@url = request.referer
```

and in the page :

```
  <%= link_to "Return", @url %>
```

But I get the link with the current page url. How can I achieve what I want.

thanks.

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. What have you tried so far? What is not working? What do you need, specifically, to move forward with your idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
= link_to "back", request.referer.present? ? request.referer : default_path
```

or in erb

```
<%= link_to "back", request.referer.present? ? request.referer : default_path %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to make a back button, you can do the following:

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Rails works out what page it is for you. I've used it on a few forms as a simple "Cancel" button.